# Combine two SQL queries on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `tableA` with different values:

```
 data
------
 10
 15
 20
 40
 40000
 50000
 60000
```

Also, I need to get some statistic information on that data (and I want to do it in one query), for example:

```
select count(data) from tableA where data < 100
union all
select count(data) from tableA  where data >= 100
```

As result, I receive

```
(No column name)
----------------
4
3
```

But I want to receive results in one row, like this:

```
Small | Big
---------
4     | 3
```

How to do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select count(case when data < 100 then 1 end) as Small,
       count(case when data >= 100 then 1 end) as Big
from TableA
```

With average it would look like this.

```
select avg(case when data < 100 then data end) as Small,
       avg(case when data >= 100 then data end) as Big
from TableA
```

Comment: Can it be easely changed to work with another expression (`AVG` for example)?

Comment: Doing the query like this, using `case when..` instead of a sub query in the field list as the other answers, has the advantage that it will only do one table scan instead of two.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why this aswer was accepted. But others are good too.

Answer (score 11):

Try sub-query instead of `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(data) FROM tableA WHERE data < 100) AS Small,
  (SELECT COUNT(data) FROM tableA WHERE data >= 100) AS Big
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d97e9/4)

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @tst TABLE (
   val INT

)

INSERT INTO @tst (val)
SELECT 10
UNION
SELEcT 15
UNION 
SELECT 20
UNION 
SELECT 40
UNION
SELECT 40000
UNION
SELECT 50000
UNION 
SELECT 60000

;WITH Smalls AS (
SELECT COUNT(val) Small FROM @tst WHERE val < 100 
), Bigs AS(
select count(val) Big from @tst where val >= 100
)
SELECT Small, Big
 FROM Smalls, Bigs
```

Comment: Actually, the other answers are much nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table datatable
(
  data int
)

insert into datatable values(10) 

insert into datatable values(15)

insert into datatable values(20)

insert into datatable values(40)

insert into datatable values(40000)

insert into datatable values(50000)

insert into datatable values(60000)



create table outputtable 
( 
  small int , 
  big int 
)

insert into outputtable 
(
  small,
  big
)

select (select count(data) from datatable where data<100),
       (select count(data) from datatable where data>=100)

select * from datatable

select * from outputtable
```